# openFileActivityBuilder intent. How to wait for it to connect and how to get the file out of it

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services

I'm using Google Drive API for android. This is the code I have right now.

```
public void downloadFromDrive(){

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();


        IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi.newOpenFileActivityBuilder().setMimeType(new String[]{"text/plain"}).build(mGoogleApiClient);
    try{
        startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender,2,null,0,0,0);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);

    }
```

}

Currently there are 2 problems with it. Since there is no resultcallback mGoogleClient doesn't connect with mGoogleApiClient.connect(). Any ideas on how to wait until it actually is connected? Using isConnected() or onConnect() only puts me in a infinite loop. I just currently connect the API client in a different method first(the one that uploads stuff)

How do I get a FileStream out of the IntentSender? I have code on how to upload to Google Drive, and I never had to specify my OutputStreamWriter in any method. I just created an Output stream, called the intentsender and the GUI uploaded the file no problem.

Comment: Try using [`enableAutoManage(FragmentActivity, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder#enableAutoManage(android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity,com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener)) which is the simplest way to manage the connection as discussed in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient).

Comment: Also see [Accessing Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client) for more information.

Comment: @Teyam yeah that appears to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the problem has been solved by the lovely people in the comments above. (enableAutoManage)

Getting a file stream out of the IntentSender can be achieved by editing the OnActivityResult method.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    System.out.println("ONACTIVITY RESULT");
    System.out.println("REQUEST CODE" + requestCode);
    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
        System.out.println("GOOGLE SIGN IN");
    }
    if(requestCode == 2){

            try{
                mDriveID  = data.getParcelableExtra(OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);
                System.out.println("ONACTIVITY DRIVE ID " + mDriveID);

            }
            catch (NullPointerException e) {
            }

    }
}
```

onActivityResults executes every time you are finished with a GoogleDrive intent(I think, not sure). So you have to catch an error in case you start an IntentSender for anything else. This isnt the most concise answer, but it worked.